# How to find a substring in given string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to find a substring in a string

If I search with MM it should be false and with MMM then it should be true. However, if I search with MM it gives me true. Please help to find substring. Input might be ABC-8102-MMM or ABC-MMM-0102 or MMM-TTR-0102

```
DECLARE @WholeString VARCHAR(50)  
DECLARE  @ExpressionToFind VARCHAR(50)  
SET @WholeString = 'ABC-MMM-0102'  
SET @ExpressionToFind = 'MM'  
   
IF @WholeString LIKE '%' + @ExpressionToFind + '%' 
    begin 
    PRINT 'Yes it is find'    
    end  
ELSE  
    PRINT 'It doesn''t find'
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, if `MMM` is a substring of something, then so is `MM`. So it sounds like you are not searching for a substring, but for something else. Please explain your expectations.

Comment: Please clearly show us the inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: i want to match MMM with MM like in C# string.Contains("MM")

Comment: You say that you expect that searching for `MM` on a string `ABC-MMM-0102` returns false, which doesn't match the behaviour of the C# `string.Contains("MM")` (which would return true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the "MMM" delimited by quotes or the beginning/end of the string.  If so, then one method is:

```
IF '-' + @WholeString + '-' LIKE '%-' + @ExpressionToFind + '-%'
```

Another method uses [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM string_split(@WhileString, '-') s WHERE s.value = @ExpressionToFind)
```

Comment: string_split() WONT WORK BECAUSE I AM USING SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: @ZoyebShaikh . . . Did you see the first part of the answer?  It is the simplest method to do what you want.  Also, nothing in your question suggests what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: thank you so much @Gordon Linoff your solution help me and sorry i didn't mention which SQL version i am using

Answer (score 1):

You can add limiting character (-) to the expression like below:

```
IF @WholeString LIKE '%-' + @ExpressionToFind + '-%' 
    OR @WholeString LIKE '%-' + @ExpressionToFind + '' 
    OR @WholeString LIKE '' + @ExpressionToFind + '-%'
    begin 
    PRINT 'Yes it is find'    
    end  
ELSE  
    PRINT 'It doesn''t find'
```

Comment: EXACTLY WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR THANK YOU  @sacse

Answer (score 0):

The string "MM" with a wildcard (%) on either end is `like` the string "MMM". The wildcard means matches any character, zero or more. So "%M" is `like` "M", and it is `like` "MM". In fact, it is `like` "(anything at all, even nothing, here)M".

Similarly, the value "%MM" is `like` "MMM". The value "%MM%" would also be `like` "MMM". It is `like` "(anything at all, even nothing, here)MM(anything at all, even nothing, here too)".

If you want to find only those cases that have "MMM", then that is what you should search for:

```
DECLARE @WholeString VARCHAR(50)  
DECLARE  @ExpressionToFind VARCHAR(50)  
SET @WholeString = 'ABC-MMM-0102'  
SET @ExpressionToFind = 'MMM'  
   
IF @WholeString LIKE '%' + @ExpressionToFind + '%' 
    begin 
    PRINT 'Yes it is find'    
    end  
ELSE  
    PRINT 'It doesn''t find'
```